# MS-Teams apps - Store app and user specific data using Teams JavaScript client SDK

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there way to store Microsoft Teams app specific  data using [Teams JavaScript client SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msteams-client?view=msteams-client-js-latest) such as Outlook add-in has [roamingSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.roamingsettings?view=outlook-js-preview) with office.js

```
Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function(result) {  //..  } });
```

Comment: Hi @InfoAsith, Could you please elaborate on the specific data that you want to store. Depending on the data we do have Graph API's to fetch information.

Comment: @Mamatha-MSFT I want to store user specific  url along with app. this is for personal tab app. similar to Channel tab app config url

Comment: You can get user specific data using getContext() it contains information about the user and teams to use it in tabs. Please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context) for more details.

Comment: @InfoAsith- Let me know does that help clarify?

Comment: @Mamatha-MSFT Thank your response.  I was looking something like this  `microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({  "myCustomProp": "https://abc_com" })` . getContext() will not helpfull for this case. since i need to store a custom value

Comment: Yes, you can set in setSettings. Did the issue got resolved?